# UDF error with firebird on linux (centOS)

Tags: linux, firebird

i try to create a UDF file for firebird on linux with C.
the function is to get left character from string.

i use this code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char EXPORT *substr(const char *str, int start, int n);
char EXPORT *leftstr(const char *nama, int jumlah);

char* substr(const char *str, int start, int n)
{
 char *pnew = (char*) malloc(n+1);
 start--;
 strncpy(pnew, str + start ,n);
 pnew[n] = '\0';
 return pnew;
}

char* leftstr(const char *nama, int jumlah)
{
 char *hasil = substr(nama,1,jumlah);
 return hasil;
}
```

then i compile it with this :

```
gcc -c -O -fpic left.c
ld -G left.o -lm -lc -o LeftUDF.so
cp LeftUDF.so /opt/firebird/udf
```

and declared it :

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION UDF_LEFTSTR_NEW
  CHAR(255) CHARACTER SET NONE,
  SMALLINT
RETURNS CHAR(255) CHARACTER SET NONE
ENTRY_POINT 'leftstr' MODULE_NAME 'LeftUDF';
```

but when i try to use it i always got error :
    Invalid token.
    Invalid request BLR at offset 63.
    Function UDF_LEFTSTR_NEW is not defined.
    Module name or entrypoint could not be found.

can somebody tell me whats wrong with it??

Comment: Have you set owner to firebird of file LeftUDF.so?

Comment: i make another simple UDF that i found around the internet, and i can use the function. i don't know why this function got error. and i didn't set any owner.

Comment: I mean that firebird cannot read your file. Just try change owner of file.
`chown firebird:firebird /opt/firebird/UDF/LeftUDF.so`

Comment: i try it, but still can't solve it..

Comment: Is `/opt/firebird/udf` whitelisted in the `Firebird.config`? Is `int` on your platform 16 bit? Otherwise the declaration should probably use `INTEGER` instead of `SMALLINT`.

Answer (score 0):

There's many aspects in FB UDF which are different from usual C programs/libs, you have to learn and follow them.

1. Exported functions must have `__stdcall` directive
2. All parameters in UDF are passed by reference (`int` parameter - wrong)
3. If UDF allocates memory, it must use special function
   `ib_util_malloc` instead of `malloc` and the keyword FREE_IT must be
   added when declaring UDF in database. Currently you have memory leak
   because the memory allocated by `malloc` never gets released.

I recommend reading UDF chapter in the Interbase 6 [dev guide](http://www.ibphoenix.com/downloads/60DevGuide.zip), it is rather old but still actual.

BTW, there's plenty of internal functions in FB including various substring extractions.